# iOS: create a struct in swift with credentials

Tags: ios, swift, struct, ios9

I have to create a `struct` to check if two UITextField are valid. 
And my idea is this, is it a good way to create a struct?

```
struct Credentials{
func isCorrect() -> Bool {
    guard let username = emailTF.text else {
        return false
    }
    guard let password = passwordTF.text else {
        return false
    }

    return true
}
```

but I have some question:

- how can I pass the values of `emailTextField` and `passwordTF` inside the struct? with an init method?
- and is it better have some var or let inside the struct or is also a good idea have only a method inside a struct?

thanks

Comment: Side note: One benefit of `guard` is the ability to cascade optional bindings `guard let username = emailTF.text, password = passwordTF.text else` { ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can creare a struct like this

```
struct Credentials {
    let email: String
    let password: String

    init?(email:String?, password: String?) {
        guard let email = email, password = password else { return  nil }
        self.email = email
        self.password = password
    }

    var correct: Bool {
        // do your check
        guard email.isEmpty == false && password.isEmpty == false else { return false }
        return true
    }
}
```

As you can see `correct` is a computed property, non a function because it does't need any params.

### Usage

```
let correct = Credentials(email: emailTF.text, password: passwordTF.text)?.correct == true
```

Answer (score 0):

Structs work roughly the same as classes. They can have variables and unlike classes if there are variables that are not explicitly given values swift will automatically create an initializer. You would do something like this.

```
let myStruct = Credentials(emailTF: "something", passwordTF: "something")
print(myStruct.isCorrect())
```

The function would use the let and var things just like a class does.

However, saying all this I would recommend just putting this function straight into your class, rather than in a struct. Just pass in values as parameters.